# How to select an option from dropdown select when value isn't known, using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, async-await, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to select the first element in a dropdown using puppeteer. The problem is that the value of the option changes every test, so I cannot select the option based off of the value unless I can retrieve that value first.

Currently using:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('#select_id > optgroup:nth-child(1) > option:nth-child(1)').selected = true;
});
```

This selects the option, however the dropdown item MUST be clicked in order for the form to submit (I do not have control over this).

I have additionally tried using Puppeteer keyboard commands to arrow down and hit enter but that functionality was not working for some reason.

Comment: Once you query the selector to select the dropdown list you can do dropdown.selectedIndex = 0; that will select the first option in the dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

Using `selected = true` on item or `selectedIndex = 0` on select will not trigger the *change* event so it will not submit your form.

I faced a similar issue and solved it with that method (using [page.evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) and [page.select](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselectselector-values)):

```
// Get the value of the first element
const value = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return document.querySelector('#select_id option:nth-child(1)').value
})

// Use it with page.select to select the item and trigger the change event
page.select('#select_id', value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) to select the first `option` in a `select` dropdown menu:

```
await page.evaluate( () =>
{
    document.getElementById( 'select_id' ).selectedIndex = 0;
});
```